# Ref Python dictionaries topic: getting different output for same input

Tags: python

Ref below image: the first dictionary has been typed by me while the second one has been copy-pasted from another source. Why execution of the 2 pieces of code is giving different results?

[Codes to compare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7orQ.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The two dictionaries are **not the same**. The age is different, and the value/subscribed keys are different. You are saving two different dictionaries into variables.

It doesn't matter whether the output is one line or multiple.
If the dictionary reaches a certain length, it will just display it in multiple lines.

Check [this](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Ip5HdOJxWi5zlfoSLPDBI96ZG4zkxB46?usp=sharing)

Comment: My bad, let me elaborate upon my query. Ref the image again: even though both the dictionaries are structured similarly, the one typed by me is returning output in a single line. While the bottom dictionary which I copy pasted (and is similar in construct as my typed dictionary) is outputting across 4 lines. Why so? I am genuinely confused.

Comment: Requested access for the resource you shared, tx in adv!

Comment: the link should be public now